# Does the dependency array in React hooks really need to be exhaustive?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect):

> every value referenced inside the effect function should also appear in the dependencies array

If my effect function references a few variables from the outer scope but I only want it to be executed when one of them changes, why do I need to specify all the other variables in the dependency array? Yes, the closure will become stale if the other variables change but I don't care because I don't need the function to be called yet. When the variable that I care about changes then the new closure with the values at that moment can be called. What am I missing?

Here's a working example (to my knowledge) where the useEffect dependency arrays are not exhaustive:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const allCars = {
    toyota: ["camry", "corolla", "mirai"],
    ford: ["mustang", "cortina", "model T"],
    nissan: ["murano", "micra", "maxima"],
};

function CarList() {
    const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
    const [brand, setBrand] = useState("toyota");
    const [filterKey, setFilterKey] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // I don't want to run this effect when filterKey changes because I wanna wrap that case in a timeout to throttle it.
        setCars(allCars[brand].filter(model => model.startsWith(filterKey)));
    }, [brand]);

    useEffect(() => {
        // This effect is only called when filterKey changes but still picks up the current value of 'brand' at the time the function is called.
        const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            setCars(allCars[brand].filter(model => model.startsWith(filterKey)));
        }, 500);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }, [filterKey]);

    const handleChangeFilterKey = event => {
        setFilterKey(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {`${brand} cars`}
            <div>Select brand</div>
            <input type="radio" value="toyota" checked={brand === "toyota"} onChange={() => setBrand("toyota")} />
            <input type="radio" value="ford" checked={brand === "ford"} onChange={() => setBrand("ford")} />
            <input type="radio" value="nissan" checked={brand === "nissan"} onChange={() => setBrand("nissan")} />
            <div>Filter</div>
            <input label="search" value={filterKey} onChange={handleChangeFilterKey} />
            <ul>
                {cars.map(car => (
                    <li>{car}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Are there any pitfalls to the above example?

Comment: No, code can work without it being exhaustive - but it's usually recommended to be exhaustive.

Comment: Nope, not at all. In fact, you can use a completely empty dependency array to indicate the effect should run only once upon component mount.

Comment: So both effects will run the first render, right?  Not terminal, but inefficient...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should follow this rule all the time, when you find your code break with following it, that means good practice is not followed. That is the meaning of this rule, make sure you design code well.

---

I imagine in your case the code looks like this:

```
  const Test = () => {
   const [wantToSync] = useState(0)
   const [notWantToSync] = useState(0) // notWantToSync also might come from props, i'll use state as example here
   useEffect(() => {
    fetch('google.com', {
      body: JSON.stringify({wantToSync, notWantToSync})
    }).then(result => {
      // ...
    })
   }, [wantToSync]) // component is supposed to be reactive to notWantToSync, missing notWantToSync in dep is dangerous
 }
```

If `notWantToSync` was defined as a **state of the component**, the component is supposed to be reactive to it, including `useEffect`. If that is not what you want, `notWantToSync` shouldn't be state from start.

```
const Test = () => {
  const [wantToSync] = useState(0)
  const notWantToSyncRef = useRef(0) // hey I don't want notWantToSync to be reactive, so i put it in useRef
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('google.com', {
      body: JSON.stringify({wantToSync, notWantToSync: notWantToSyncRef.current})
    }).then(result => {
      // ...
    })
  }, [wantToSync, notWantToSyncRef]) // yeah, now eslint doesn't bother me, and notWantToSync doesn't trigger useEffect anymore
}
```

Normally you don't need to do if else in useEffect to stop re-rendering, there're other approaches like `useMemo` or `useCallback` to do similar things in addition to `useRef` although they have different using context.

---

I see your struggle in the new example, so you want to do a throttle, and if `filterKey` is added to the first useEffect dep, the throttle will be broken. My opinion is that when you find yourself in a situation like this, that often means there's better practice(eslint exhaustive help to identify it), for example, extract throttle logic to a hook: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useThrottle.ts.

Exhaustive deps is not something vital to follow, it's just a good practice to make sure your code is designed well. The above example proves it that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This doesn't answer the question more than the quote from the docs. When you say it will make sure I don't miss necessary dependencies, you're making the assumption that I'm questioning. Why are the dependencies necessary, given the stuff I said. And for me it does hurt. In a situation where I want my function to be called only when one variable changes, now it gets called when any variable changes so I have to add additional checks and complicate the logic. Moreover the hook now needs to scan a longer array which may not be a big deal in most cases but why add [cont...]

Comment: [...cont] more computation than is necessary.

Comment: hey @NissanMurano, sorry for the confusion, I have added more details

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer. I see you added a solution for specifying dependencies that don't trigger the effect function. That definitely would work but is it really any different from just not specifying them? The value underneath is still changing, useEffect just can't detect it because it's wrapped in an object. Similarly to how it can’t detect a variable that’s just not specified at all.

Comment: Regardless of that, I think your answer is still begging the question. I still don’t know the reason why I should specify all dependencies other than “you should do it”. I added an example code that omits some dependencies and does not seem to have bugs. Unless someone can point them out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for providing the example, in fact, this example proves that the exhaustive deps rule is useful, because it can make sure you don't fall into situation like that. Have included more details in the answer

Comment: Very cool solution. I agree it's better. But I wonder if the code inside both effects wasn't identical, i.e. filterKey change should trigger funA(brand, filterKey) and brand change should trigger funB(brand, filterKey), would that be a good candidate for non-exhaustive deps? Or do you think there might still a better exhaustive solution?
Thanks for your patience btw. I know it's many follow-ups. I just want to understand the core reason why it's good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is **no side-effect**, it's just data **derived** from state, so you should use different tools instead of `useEffect`.

First filter could be implemented with just getting value by key:

```js
const carsByBrand = allCars[brand];
```

Complexity of this operation is constant, so memoization will be too expensive.

And second filter is **debounced**, but you might want to **memoize** it because of filtering with linear complexity. For these purposes you can use for example [useDebouncedMemo](https://github.com/SevenOutman/use-debounced-memo) hook:

```js
const filteredCars = useDebouncedMemo(() => {
   return carsByBrand.filter(model => model.startsWith(filterKey)
}, [filterKey, carsByBrand], 500)
```

In this case dependencies of hook are exhaustive and logic is much more declarative.